# Is there a way to connect Oracle from MySQL

Tags: oracle, mysql, oracleforms

Can any one suggest me if there is a way to connect Oracle from MySQL please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a DB Link in MySql to connect to Oracle database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092636/how-to-create-a-db-link-in-mysql-to-connect-to-oracle-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, no.

`MySQL` supports `FEDERATED` storage engine which is similar to `Linked Servers` / `Remote Servers` used by another systems, but as for the moment, it only supports remote `MySQL` servers.

There is a way to connect `MySQL` from `Oracle`, though, using `Oracle Database Gateway`.