# Connect to an Oracle View from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

Is there a way to connect to an Oracle View from MySQL?

My scenario is the following: In the company we have built a system entirely on MySQL and we have some views to display consolidated data. Due to a recent initiative to connect to the company's central database we have to connect to some of the tables in an Oracle DB instead of the ones in MySQL.

The idea is to transparently connect to Oracle, with the minimum possible impact, ideally, just changing the references from MySQL tables to the Oracle views.

Is it possible to achieve this in an optimal way? What could be the best option?

Previous research: Looking into similar questions here in SO, I wasn't able to find accepted or proved answers. I'm newbie in such kind of integration.

Comment: This question has your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092636/how-to-create-a-database-link-in-mysql-to-connect-to-oracle

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure if it is the same case but will review the workarounds of the most voted answer to see what works. The main link of the first answer is not accesible at the moment (forbidden).

Comment: Switch to MariaDB. Its a binary replacement from MySQL. There you have a CONNECT Storage Engine. Over this you can Connent to other Database .

Comment: Thank you, that sounds good, I will review it.

Comment: I was able to get a previous version of the forbidden page from archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20141113060908/http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/dbixmyserver.html
It seems to be what I was looking for. I also will give a try to MariaDB.